# Permission denied error after given 0777 permission to var/ folder in Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3.1, file-permissions

I am using Magento 2.3.1 and I am getting that error on my Magento after given 0777 permission on my var folder

i am using that command : -sudo chmod -R 0777 var/

> Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file
>
> "/var/www/html//var/log/system.log" could not be opened: failed to
>
> open stream: Permission denied in
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107

and my permission is

```
drwxr-xr-x.  5 apache apache   64 Aug 20 16:21 .
drwxr-xr-x. 17 apache apache 4096 Aug 19 21:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root   root     36 Aug 20 16:21 cache
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root     34 Aug 20 16:21 composer_home
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  124 Aug 20 16:37 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root     39 Aug 20 16:29 log
```

So please help me..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try below steps:-**

```
sudo rm -rf var/*
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
sudo rm -rf generated/*

sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
```

Comment: try this commands

Answer (score 2):

**try giving permission using this command**

> sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/jazz/var/log